# Using the proper tense in a comparsion

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english, comparison, sequence-of-tenses

Which of the following seems more idiomatic for natives.

1-I have been practicing recently more than I had been in the past.

2-I have been practicing recently more than I used to in the past .

3-I have been practicing recently more than I did in the past .

Comment: They all mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

Although your meaning is clear in each of these, none of them are actually natural English.

Instead, try:

> Recently, I have been practicing more.

or

> I've been practicing more than I had previously.

or

> I have recently been practicing more than I used to.

You do not need to use both 'recently' and 'in the past' to make that comparison.

The placement of 'recently' is incorrect in all three sentences in your question.

If you use one of have / had / had been to refer to the past - the time where you were practicing less is in the past, so the correct choice is "had" or 'had been'. ('Have been" is for something that started in the past and continues up to or through the present.)